# preview: why the table layout in preview is different than without it?

Tags: preview

I try to give a variant to David Carslisle answer on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206991/problem-with-vertical-alignment-of-cells-in-tabular-environment). To better see obtained results I use `preview` package. I was surprised, that I obtain different result in comparison when I not use it! My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,paralist}%enumitem

%\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{>{\centering}m{0.8in}}
                     >{\centering}m{01.5in}
                     >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{01.5in}}
    \hline
\bfseries Heading 1 
        &  \bfseries Heading 2 
            &   \bfseries Heading 3 
                &   \bfseries Heading 4 
                    &   \bfseries Heading Heading Heading 5 
                        &   \bfseries Heading Heading Heading 6   \\
\hline
text    &   text    &   text    &   text    &
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{3in+2\tabcolsep}@{}}{
                \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{1.5in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}}%{p{1.5in}p{1.5in}}
                    \begin{compactitem}[\textbullet]
                    \item text text text text tex text text text text text text text
                    \end{compactitem}
                                            &   \begin{compactitem}[\textbullet]
                            \item text text text text text text text text
                            \item text text text text text text text text
                                            \end{compactitem}
                \end{tabular}\vspace*{-1ex}}                     \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

With use of `preview` package i receive:
[image]

Without `preview` package the columns 5 and 6 are aligned on the top. Do I miss some option in `preview` package or is this some bug? As I understand `preview`, it should not influence on content of tables, pictures and math.